# multiple 1 to 0..1 relationships to the same Primary Key on parent table in entity framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Say I have the following objects

- Weapon
- Sword
- Rifle
- Bow

I want the following structure.

- The weapon can only be 1 of those but has to be atleast 1.
- All weapons must be stored in the same place.
- all weapons types must be stored in their own corresponding tables like Swords,Rifles,Bows. (Without duplicating data)

This is what I have done. 
I created an interface called `IWeapon` which looks like this

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Weapon")]
    public int WeaponId { get; set; }

    
    public Weapon Weapon{ get; set; }
}
```

Here are my other classes

```
public class Weapon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Damage { get; set; }

    public IWeapon ActualWeapon { get; set; }
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Weapon")]
    public int WeaponId { get; set; }

    public Weapon Weapon{ get; set; }

    //other properties and methods
}

//same for Rifle and Bow
```

After defining my structure I tried to get it working in Entity Framework Core.
I did the following in my dbcontext to get the 1 to 1 relationships set up

```
public DbSet<Weapon> Weapons { get; set; }

public DbSet<Sword> Swords { get; set; }

public DbSet<Rifle> Rifles { get; set; }

public DbSet<Bow> Bows { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Weapon>()
      .HasOne(w => (Sword)w.ActualWeapon)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<Sword>(WeaponT => WeaponT.WeaponId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Weapon>()
      .HasOne(w => (Rifle)w.ActualWeapon)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<Rifle>(WeaponT => WeaponT.WeaponId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Weapon>()
      .HasOne(w => (Bow)w.ActualWeapon)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<Bow>(WeaponT => WeaponT.WeaponId);
}
```

My problem I am facing is that only the last created relationships works. so in this case the Bow's will work, Assuming its because all the relationships are going to the same column then it doesn't know which one to fecth and bases it of the casting that I did with the modelbuilder

Is there a way to set up multiple 1 to 0..1 relationships to the same column while still maintaining most of this structure

Comment: your tables look weird. Why not just 1 table "Weapon" and this table has column called "WeaponType" (bow, sword, etc)? If want to have different types of swords, create another new table "WeaponType" with "ID", "WeaponID", "Name" (Dragon Sword, Snake Sword...), "Damage".

Comment: Currently EF Core does not support (cannot map) such model. You have to revisit your design, or replace the interface with abstract class and (1) remove the separate table requirement and use the exiting TPH mapping or (2) wait for EF Core 5.0 and TPT mapping

Comment: Sadly the design is pretty locked because its interlinked with other systems. This was the simplest way I could explain without giving IP away but keeps the full structure to give a solvable question. each weapon type is managed by a different company in my situation

Comment: @IvanStoev Do you know when TPT Mapping will be completed. I read on TPT and also think it can solve my problem

Comment: EF Core 5.0 is [scheduled for November 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/#ef-core-50). TPT is already available in [Preview 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#table-per-type-tpt-mapping).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Run scaffold-dbcontext command.

### DbContext.cs

```
public virtual DbSet<TWeapon> TWeapon { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<TWeaponType> TWeaponType { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TWeapon>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("T_Weapon");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(100);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<TWeaponType>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("T_WeaponType");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.Damage).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

        entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(100);

        entity.Property(e => e.WeaponId).HasColumnName("WeaponID");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Weapon)
            .WithMany(p => p.TWeaponType)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.WeaponId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_T_WeaponType_T_Weapon");
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

### TWeapon.cs

```
public partial class TWeapon
    {
        public TWeapon()
        {
            TWeaponType = new HashSet<TWeaponType>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TWeaponType> TWeaponType { get; set; }
    }
```

### TWeaponType.cs

```
public partial class TWeaponType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? WeaponId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal? Damage { get; set; }

        public virtual TWeapon Weapon { get; set; }
    }
```

### Get weapons

```
var weapons = db.TWeapon.Include(x => x.TWeaponType).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: TWeapon table name should be TWeaponType. TWeaponType table name should be TWeapon. More appropriate. TWeaponType (Sword, Bow, Rifle). TWeapon (Dragon sword, Snake sword...)

Comment: This is a very to the book type of solution and will work in almost any other scenario.. Sadly I can not go this route. Will give you a thumbs up though